# Angular 5: How can we use same directive for restricting input field and showing text in label for html

Tags: angular5, angular2-directives

I created one directive to accept number only in input. But I also want to show some text in label according to the value entered. Can I get variable from directive to component?

```
@Directive({
  selector: '[OnlyNumber]'
})

export class OnlyNumber {

  regexStr = '^[0-9]*$';
  //regexStr = ".*[^0-9].*";
  constructor(private el: ElementRef) { }

  @Input() OnlyNumber: boolean;
  @Output() tabText: boolean;           //trying to use this for component

  @HostListener('keydown', ['$event']) onKeyDown(event) {
    let e = <KeyboardEvent>event;
    let keyCode = e.keyCode;
    if (this.OnlyNumber) {
      let ch = String.fromCharCode(keyCode);
      let regEx = new RegExp(this.regexStr);
      if (regEx.test(ch)){
        this.tabText = true;            //trying to use this for component
        return;
      } else {
        e.preventDefault();
      }
    }
  }
}
```

// HTML

```
<input name="salesprice" type="text" OnlyNumber="true" [(ngModel)]="salesprice" >
```

I want to display the below label if tabText variable is set to true. Please assist.

```
<label>text entered.</label>
```

Answer (score 0):

For a number only field you can use

```
<input name="salesprice" type="number" OnlyNumber="true" [(ngModel)]="salesprice" >
```

And to set label only when the `tabText` is set you can use

```
<label *ngIf = "tabText">text entered.</label>
```

Comment: Actually I used onlynumber directive for specific requicrement. That number will contain comma separated value and 2 decimal points. So cannot use type=number.

Comment: I tried this as well. But I am not able get tabIndex in component or html.